# Looking for a free Windows command-line PDF restrictions remover

Tags: windows, gratis, pdf, command-line

As the title states I'm looking for a free self-contained portable command-line Windows utility that can remove any PDF's restrictions (such as copying text, printing and so on). Ideally it should support all versions up to [Acrobat 9.1 PDFs](https://www.adobe.com/devnet/pdf/pdf_reference.html). This is for personal use only on files I own.

Comment: In case you don't realize, there are also PDF viewers that can ignore DRM, such as Okular.

Comment: Kodiologist, I'm using certain command-line tools to transform the PDFs into a format I prefer, but since these tools do not ignore DRM I need to strip the files of restrictions first. Hence the request and why a simple viewer like Okular just won't do. (Again, this is strictly for personal use only on files I own.)